# Loop within column name

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a data frame with columns car_x and car1_y, van2_x and van2_y, and bus3_x and bus3_y. I need a column that is car1_x * car1_y + van2_x * van2_y + bus3_x * bus3_y

The following code doesn't work:

```
modes = 'car', 'van', 'bus'

for mode in modes:
    df['{var}'] = df['{var}_x']*df['{var}_y']
```

I would then just sum across df['car'], df['van'] and df['bus'] but the syntax above is off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your code, you'd need to use f-strings in order to let python know that `{var}` should be inserted as its value and not the string `"{var}"`.

```
for mode in modes:
    df[f'{var}'] = df[f'{var}_x'] * df[f'{var}_y']
```

But this would need an additional sum step to get "result".

```
df['result'] = df[list(modes)].sum(axis=1)
```

---

Let's cut out the extra step and do this a lot faster, using `einsum` here. Filter out your `_x` and `_y` columns, and then use `einsum` to specify a sum-of-products operation.

```
x = df.filter(like='_x')
y = df.filter(like='_y')

df['result'] = np.einsum('ij,ij->i', x, y)
```

Thanks to the `filter` step, there is no longer a need to maintain a separate `modes` list anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the f. Your code is cleaner though.

Answer (score 2):

I will using `groupby`

```
df.groupby(df.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1).prod()[['car', 'van', 'bus']].sum(1)
```